# How to solve $Cx^2 y'' + xy'- y = 0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, power-series

How to solve the differential equation $Cx^2 y'' + xy'- y = 0$, if $C$ is positive?

Attempt: I use power series and let
$$y = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^{n+c}$$
be the solution. Getting the first and second derivatives and substituting these into the given DE, I obtained
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} [C(n+c)(n+c-1)] a_n x^{n+c} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+c) a_n x^{n+c} - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^{n+c} =0$$
What should we continue here? If this is not the optimal solution or approach, what would you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$Cx^2 y'' + xy'- y = 0$$
$$C y'' +\dfrac { xy'- y}{x^2} = 0$$
$$C y'' +\left (\dfrac { y}{x}\right)' = 0$$
Integrate.